# Spring pageContext.request.contextPath with Tomcat behind Apache as reverse proxy

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat

I run a Spring App on a remote server where is installed a Tomcat Server which give access to my app via `https://mydom.com:8080/myapp`.

To make my app accessible via `https://mydom.com`, I installed Apache and configured as reverse proxy.

This is configuration:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

   SSLEngine On

   SSLCertificateFile /opt/ssl/mydom_com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/ssl/mydom_com.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/ssl/mydom_com.ca-bundle

   BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

   ServerName mydom.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
   ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myapp /

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I try to use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` in my `jsp` files to get the right links and resources path.

When I run from IDE it return `/myapp`, which is good.

When run on `mydom.com` it return `/myapp`, which is not good. I need to get an empty string or `/`.

How I can configure to get right value for `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`?

Comment: what you want to access through that url `mydom.com`?

Comment: my app from tomcat which run via `https://mydom.com:8080/myapp`. But I have done that with apache. My problem is at `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`. On `mydom.com` it returns `/myapp` which is `contextPath` from tomcat: `https://mydom.com:8080/myapp`. On `mydom.com` I want `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` to be equal with `'/'` or `''(empty string)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your mapping from:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myapp /
```

to:

```
ProxyPass /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
```

And all your problems will be solved.

Trying to re-write context paths in the proxying is the #1 cause of insanity in Tomcat administrators. Just don't do it.

If you want your application available on `/`, then do one of these things:

1. Re-direct `/` to `/myapp/` and use my re-written mapping above
2. Re-name your application from `/myapp/` to `/` on the Tomcat end and fix your mapping to map `/` -> `/`

Any other configuration will be an endless cycle of band-aids, fix-ups and band-aids-to-fix-ups that you will have to apply.

Comment: Thank you. First option is excluded for me. I want my website to be accessible via `mydom.com`, not `mydom.com/myapp`. So I picked second option. I renamed my app `ROOT.war` and copied in `webapps` folder. There can be another way to done it or only `ROOT.war` is the only way?

Comment: You have a [few options](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context), but `ROOT.war` is pretty much the easiest possible way.